# How to get key value fashion json output while scraping using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My data is like this, repeated for different companies likewise

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div class="result-container" id="main">
    <div>
      <ul class="search-results-container">
        <div data-testid="downloadCompanyCard">
          <li class="search-result-item sr-collapsed ">
            <div class="ant-row ant-row-start ant-row-top search-item-row spacer-small-bottom search-item-row-padding-bottom"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24px" class="sr-collapse-button" data-testid="CompanyCardClose24Px">
                                    </svg>
              <div class="ant-col ant-col-20 results-col-padding">
                <div class="results-info paragraph">
                  <div></div>
                  <div><a class="results-name strong" href="/company/2c257c50-0f76-3886-914d-4ead9d3ea998">Republic of kazinboom</a> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ant-row ant-row-start ant-row-top relative-day-ago relative-day-row-padding">
              <div class="ant-col ant-col-14 company-vitals-col-padding">
                <div class="paragraph" data-testid="CompanyCardVitals">
                  <div class="inlined-card-info"><span class="strong">Kyonesto, County of Cukaliya</span>
                    <div data-testid="CompanyCardVitalsPhone"><span class="dot dark"></span><span class="no-wrap">+0-765-543-4321</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div>Top Executive and Legislature</div>
                  <div>Public Sector<span class="dot dark"></span>Parent<span class="dot dark" data-testid="CompanyCardVitalsHQHeader"></span>Headquarters</div>
                  <div data-testid="CompanyCardVitalsCompcode">AL-P-H-A: 12-345-6789</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ant-col ant-col-10">
                <div class="ant-row ant-row-no-wrap ant-row-start ant-row-top">
                  <div class="ant-col ant-col-none ant-col-md-16 ant-col-lg-14 ant-col-xl-14">
                    <div data-testid="CompanyCardStatsId" class="ant-row ant-row-start ant-row-top">
                      <div class="ant-col ant-col-none grid-data grid-data-sales">
                        <table class="paragraph">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr data-testid="CompanyCardStatsAssets">
                              <td>Assets:</td>
                              <td>1100.50T</td>
                              <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr data-testid="CompanyCardStatsEmployees">
                              <td>Employees (HQ):</td>
                              <td>1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr data-testid="CompanyCardStatsEmployeesTotal">
                              <td>Employees (Total):</td>
                              <td>92002.768886B</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ant-col ant-col-none trigger-signals-column" style="flex: 1 1 auto; min-width: 0px;">
                    <div class="company-card-ideal-profile-score spacer-small-bottom"></div>
                    <div class="text-align-right"><small>Added: 13-Apr-2023</small></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My current python selenium code, gets me text out of it

```py
tdata = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]').text
    with open('testdata.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(tdata,f)
```

Now output I get is plain text.

What I want to achieve is to get `key:value` like output, to facilitate easy integration with other applications, not all company records will have all fields (e.g. there may not be assets reported for other companies). In such a case, having `key:value` ( asset:1trillion) helps.

And for the fields which don't have a tag associated,(e.g. `company_name`), I want to add a fix key name that says `"company_name":"Republic..."`

Appreciate any pointers

Comment: You already seem to know how to get text off the page, what is stopping you from getting the data you want?

Comment: Hi @JeffC, I am trying to get like "tag name" : "tag_value"

# here there is no tag as well which shows its Company (so need to add manually)
"Company" : "Republic of kazinboom"

#here tag available if I can get it somehow
"CompanyCardVitals":"Kyonesto, County of Cukaliya"  
"CompanyCardVitalsCompcode":"AL-P-H-A: 12-345-6789"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need to first fetch the list of company details and store into a separate list.
Then create a dictionary object and to load the values.

```
companyName=[item.text for item in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]//a[@class="results-name strong"]')]
CompanyCardVitals=[item.text for item in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]//div[@class="inlined-card-info"]/span')]
CompanyCardVitalsCompcode=[item.text for item in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]//div[@data-testid="CompanyCardVitalsCompcode"]')]

data={"company_Name" : companyName,"Company_CardVitals" :CompanyCardVitals, "Company_CardVitalsCompcode" : CompanyCardVitalsCompcode}
print(data)
```

---

Or If you only one record then it should be like that.

```
data={"company_Name" :  browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]//a[@class="results-name strong"]'),"Company_CardVitals" :browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]//div[@class="inlined-card-info"]/span'), "Company_CardVitalsCompcode" : browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]//div[@data-testid="CompanyCardVitalsCompcode"]')}
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @KunduK , I will shortly update on acceptance as solution

Comment: Hey thanks again, further I added alldata=[] ul_items = companies_ul.find_elements(By.XPATH,'.//*[@data-testid="downloadCompanyCard"]')
for item in ul_items:alldata.append(data)   like wise for all attributes